# Using Bibtex with LyX help

Tags: bibtex, pdf, lyx, compiling

I am currently using LyX, and I have a .bib file with all of my BibTeX references.  Everything seems to work fine at first, but then goes terribly wrong when I try to view the pdf.

I have added the .bib file in LyX by going:  `Insert -> List/TOC -> Bibtex Bibliography` and it seems to work perfectly fine.  When I click `Insert -> Citation`, all of my references appear, and I can click them easily and put them where I like.

Now here is the strange part:  Lets say for example that I cite two different papers in my LyX document, and then view it as a pdf.  Where I referenced the documents, there will be the numbers [1] or [2], depending on, which is exactly what I want, however the References section is all wrong.  At the end of the paper, the references section will have the numbers [1] and [2], but **no text** following, just blank.  It is just a blank references section with the numbers [1] and [2], that is all.  What is going on here?  Why didn't it put in the information which is in my BibteX file?

Thanks for your help,

**Edit:** When I convert the lyx document to LaTeX, this is the code which appears at the end  `\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}\bibliography{bibtex_file_name}`

Do I have to do something extra to my bibtex file to make it work?  At the moment it is just a TeX file saved as .bib with text of the form  `@article {ArticleName
    AUTHOR = {},
    TITLE = {},
    ETC.... }`

Comment: Can you post one bibtex item of your .bib file?

Comment: I just asking because the right structure of bibtex item is @article{ArticleName, author = {}, title = {}, ETC...}

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solves. I voted to close this question as _too localized_, since I don't really regard a typo like this as a real problem with a distinct solution. The question might even be deleted afterwards, but that's just to keep the site tidy and keep its content maximally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget the comma between the string `ArticleName` and command `AUTHOR`.

So your bibtex should be:

```
@article {DeBruijn1951, AUTHOR = {de Bruijn, N. G.}, 
TITLE = {On the number of positive integers {$\leq x$} and free of prime factors {$>y$}}, 
JOURNAL = {Nederl. Acad. Wetensch. Proc. Ser. A.}, 
VOLUME = {54}, YEAR = {1951}, PAGES = {50--60}, MRCLASS = {10.0X},
MRNUMBER = {0046375 (13,724e)}, MRREVIEWER = {P. T. Bateman}, }
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved my problem, I can't believe it was just a comma...!